# Materialize sideNav() and dropdown() not working

Tags: jquery, html, web, materialize

I started HTML few weeks ago and I have a problem.
I create my website with materialize framework and I have trouble when using initializing sideNav() or dropdown(). What's the problem ? I followed guides on http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html
Hope you will help me ! (Sorry if my english is not perfect, i'm french)

[image: The error i get][image: where is the error]

Comment: You have typo, use `.slideNav()`

Comment: @JozefDúc no... it's `.sideNav()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are loading the jQuery library twice. I suggest you remove the last one(at line 271).

Comment: Oh yeah... Thanks a lot ! It worked ! I'm still a beginner ^^

Answer (score 1):

use script tag at last

```html
<body>
  content..then function atlast
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
        </script>
  </body>
```